# Filter Record Set Before Populating ADO.NET Object

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports, ado.net

I used [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ckiFB6txfpc&ab_channel=FoxLearn) to build a Crystal Report in my application. The tutorial guides the user through developing an ADO.NET object and then populating it with data. I am also using a Parameter in the Crystal Report to limit the data set. The issue I'm having is that loading the report is slow and I wonder if it's because I have to load more data than I actually need before the Crystal Report employs the Parameter filter.

Following is my existing code, which runs on the report viewer form Load event. I'd like to adjust the code below to pass a parameter so I can filter the data as it's loaded rather than loading a bunch of data I know I won't need or use.

```cs
private void InspectionReportSerial2_Viewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    International_PZD_PRDEntities db = new International_PZD_PRDEntities();
    var list = db.vw_Nightly_and_Inspections.Select(p=>new {ID = p.ID,
        SerialNumber = p.SerialNumber, ProductionOrder = p.ProductionOrder,
        Product=p.Product, Customer=p.Customer, SalesOrder = p.SalesOrder,
        LineItem = p.LineItem, Section=p.Section,InspectionPoint=p.InspectionPoint,
        Status=p.Status,SectionSignoffBy = p.SectionSignoffBy,
        SectionSignoffCheck=p.SectionSignoffCheck,
        SectionSignoffDate = p.SectionSignoffDate,HardwareSerial=p.HardwareSerial,
        SectionSortString = p.SectionSortString, ItemSortString = p.ItemSortString,
        Comment = p.Comment});
    InspectionReportSerial21.SetDataSource(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `Where`. Since you are not describing the kind of filtering you need, I can only give an example:

```cs
private void InspectionReportSerial2_Viewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    International_PZD_PRDEntities db = new International_PZD_PRDEntities();
    var list = db.vw_Nightly_and_Inspections
        .Where(p => p.Customer == "Dekxblock")
        .Select(p => new { ID = p.ID, SerialNumber = p.SerialNumber, ... });
    InspectionReportSerial21.SetDataSource(list);
}
```

I don't know what `International_PZD_PRDEntities` is. If it is some kind of O/R-mapper (e.g., EF or EF Core), then this will filter the records on the database side, which is faster than filtering the data in your application, because less records have to be transmitted. If not, then you should execute a query like `SELECT * FROM vw_Nightly_and_Inspections WHERE Customer = 'Dekxblock'` including the filter. Make sure to use [Command.Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I needed. I didn't dare hope it would be this easy.Thanks, Olivier!